# Is it good to use $state.reload() onload of a controller?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In ionic project I want to clear the history then remove back button then bring back the bar button in the nav.

To do this i used, following code

```
$timeout(function() {
    $ionicHistory.clearHistory();
    $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBar(true);
    $ionicNavBarDelegate.showBackButton(false);        
}, 1000);
```

I am successfully able to remove the back button, but the bar button is appearing only if I put `$state.reload()`, now **my question** is

If I use `$state.reload()` then will the controller will reload again and again? or it will reload only once. Yes I know now you must be saying that, why don't you test and check? I have already tested but in my system the code is running once, but once I encounter this kind of problem after using `$state.reload()` the controller was called infinitely.

So, this is why I am not sure if we can use `$state.reload()` on load of a controller or not.

Please help!

Comment: why are you doing this ? i mean clear cache and hide back button and so on

Comment: because instead of back button i need bar button in the project, along with that I need to clear history so that user shall not use the back of the device to go back